# My first PCB design. 4x4 CNY70 matrix read by breakout board

Tags: pcb-design, autorouter

Please give my design a once over. I think I have found everything but I am nervous.

This is my first PCB design. A 4x4 [CNY70](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83751/cny70.pdf) (Reflective Optical Sensor) matrix read by a analog/digital mux breakout board. This PCB is meant to mount into a musical instrument which is also my first CAD design. It has been a long self taught process.

With this PCB design the emitter is always on and a micro controller selects s0-s3 to read 1-16 inputs. Only 1-16 IN, GRD, and VCC connect to this board.

The Mux board is mounted from underneath to allow for greater clearance. This is needed so the CNY70 can mount more or less flush to its case. The holes will not have any mechanical stress applied but I tried giving the traces as large a margin as possible.

I redesigned this using through hole because I thought it would be easier for doing by hand at home.

I considered redesigning again to use a larger 220 ohm resistor because it might be easier to get, but the board is looking a bit cramped. Right now they are 1/6w but 1/8w should work too. Emitter and detector are both 100mW.

[image]

[image: Resistors may need to be mounted on the back for more clearance.]

Comment: What is CNY70, this one? https://www.vishay.com/docs/83751/cny70.pdf

Comment: Yes it is that.

Comment: Do you have any schematic, or are you following any tutorial? This one? https://hackaday.com/2010/10/07/playing-piano-with-optical-sensors/

Comment: How fast will you be strobing though your matrix?

Comment: Sensing area of CNY70 seems to be quite large, hope that's not a problem for your application.

Comment: There is someone who used those resistor values for that voltage at that voltage for CNY70. I screwed up the schematic file with making changes directly to the PCB.

Comment: How are you going to use the holes, there's no clearance for a nut or screw head?

Comment: I don't know exactly how fast I would be strobing through the matrix. But I plan on using a teensy 4.1 and going about as fast as I can. I know higher frequencies can cause problems. But I plan on connecting 4 boards. Sending the change signal to the mux, and then reading the 4 new values.

Comment: The holes allow for a shaft to slide past. Part of a custom button. It should not ever touch the PCB.

Comment: This video was why I went with cny70 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OInd2ybB2uA&t=174s 
KontinuumLAB makes a lot of instruments with this optical sensors.

Comment: A schematic is needed even if you have to recreate all over again.

Comment: The traces look like 8 mil or 0.2 mm width. There is enough space to use 12 mil or 0.3 mm width. The resistance of the traces would be lower and the traces would be more robust. Traces used for VCC and GND should be at least 20 mil or 0.5 mm. There are many traces missing. The capacitors between VCC and GND to buffer the supply voltage are missing. They should be used together with high speed CMOS logic.

Comment: You can definitely use surface-mount resistors here. It might be hard without practice to solder anything smaller than 0603, but 0805 and definitely 1206 are trivial to solder by hand. Just solder the resistors first so the sensors don't get in the way.

Comment: I worried about increasing the size of traces because it would increase impedance but maybe it is to such a negligible degree I should not worry.

Comment: I will add a bypass capacitor. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/566921/what-capacitor-value-should-i-use-for-3-3v-from-a-buck-converter-ic   this post talks about correct capacitor size for 3.3v. 10nf ceramic seems like it might be reasonable. Larger capacitor should be fine too I guess. I want accurate and fast reads but the values should not change very fast because they are reading key presses. But as I understand how the mux works it is not opening a gate and letting current through, rather it is reading a value, so the current should not drop much at any point.

Comment: Is it possible you are actually mounting the CYN70 parts on the bottom of the PCB? The 3D image and markings below CYN70 number 2 would seem to indicate they are being mounted on the top. If the CYN70 parts are on the top then the pin labeled GND looks to be going to the anode and collector of all the CYN70 parts, (which would be wrong). If the parts are on the opposite side you usually want the displayed silk screen color to be different so the layer difference is easily recognized.

Comment: I had some confusion about how this part i wired. This is in part because the LED side can only be connected one way but the transistor side can by wired either way. So you either wire together the pins ground diagonally and then have resistors and signal on the positive side. Or you wire the positive pins together and have resistors on the ground side as is more typical. But I think they are equivalent. Anyway because I switched the way it was wired at one point and did not do the change in the proper way. I went back and did it over again to make sure it is correct. Came out cleaner anyway.

Comment: As fast as you can, can you please put a number on that? I suspect you need to pay more attention to layout and decoupling capacitors for signal integrity.

Comment: You definitely aren't wrong. Not doing so would be settling for more noise and less precision then I could get. But I might have to do that. The board is very full without switching to surface mount. Also I am not quite sure where the capacitors should go. Would it be between the detector vcc pin on the cny70 and the detector pin being used as the data pin? And the value I am guessing 1000pf might be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Summing up the general advice I got.

1. Power and ground traces should be .5mm if possible. Other traces should be .3mm. This is to reduce resistance, and make more robust traces that will break less. I also increased pad size for the same reason.
2. Add bypass capacitors where appropriate. At least 1. I can always not populate it if not needed. Bigger capacitor = more smoothing, less frequency response. Ceramic is a good choice because of stability and responsiveness.
3. Double check your design and keep the schematic up to date even if you have to remake it.
4. Add the silk screen on the side with the part. Though I am ignoring this as to only have one side silk screened.

I did it over and I think it came out better.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking at your second design and by doing some alternate layouts myself I do see that placing the 16 pin connector at the center is a better option. However from your first description this didn't seem to be an option. Also, since you have several pins passing through the PCB be sure you know the tolerances needed from the hole edges. If the pins are metal you don’t want traces or pads contacting them. The pins might also create stress or twisting forces at the hole edges, this might later break a trace running close to the holes. Using a larger keep-out ring around each hole may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One of the arrangements I’ve attached below would be closer to how I would layout the board with the components you originally included.  (Note that I created a new silkscreen for the sensor.)

While placing a few components diagonally obviously will not change any electrical functionality it can give the appearance that something went amiss with the layout design or there were last minute corrections required.

As for the bypass cap: A 0.1uf or even a 1.0uf ceramic bypass cap would be better in most cases.  The proper placement to reduce incoming or outgoing noise would be very close to the GND and 3.3v pins, in your case to the left or just below the GND pin. Once you start getting away from the input power pins with a few twists and turns you begin to lose some effectiveness.

Another way to reduce board noise would be to use a full top or bottom GND pour, that way your return currents will follow the path of least impedance and you could also reduce most or all of the routed GND traces. To make the best use of a GND pour you would need to place most of your signal traces on the side opposite the pour.

For your comment about connecting the detector side differently: While a transistor will often work somewhat normally when the collector and emitter are swapped some transistor parameters may not match their original specifications.  If you are using the transistor detector side in such a fashion I hope you've verified that the operation is satisfactory for your specific system design.

Silkscreen:  Assuming your sensors are actually mounted on the bottom side and you only want top side silkscreen it might be best to revise the LED and transistor symbols you've added, otherwise someone troubleshooting the board at a later time could become quite confused. (Just in case your sensors are actually mounted on the top side then I think there are still connection problems.)

Placing silkscreen information under the physical part is not ideal (except perhaps for the first time assembler).  Once assembled the information is very difficult to read.  If you are using through hole resistors the values are often right on the part as either text or color bands. A better documenting option is to use the component’s part list ID such a R1, R2, etc. positioned to the edge of the component’s physical position.

Alternate layouts:

[image]

[image]